# How to validate AWS Redis In Transit and At Rest encryption?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, redis-cluster

We have set up the AWS Redis Cluster with **In transit encryption and encryption at rest**. How can we validate this encryption because if we call Redis with a key then we are getting plain value.